# How to curl/wget a script, run it with arguments, and make its functions available locally?

Tags: bash, curl, wget, subshell

This function will either use cURL or wGet to download a script and execute it with additional arguments:

```bash
wexec() {
    url=$1
    shift
    if command -v "curl" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        curl -s $url | bash -s -- $@
    elif command -v "wget" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        wget -qO- $url | bash -s -- $@
    else
        echo "No curl or wget found."
        return 1
    fi
}
```

I want to download and run the following script from a server and run it locally with passed arguments:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
hello() {
    echo Hello World!
}
echo Arguments: $@
```

I also want the `hello` function to be available in the local environment, but it's not, because I defined it in a <s>subshell</s> new shell, so calling `wexec http://example.org/my-remote-script.sh a1 a2 a3; hello` will successfully output `Arguments: a1 a2 a3`, but fail with `hello: command not found`.

Is there a way to send arguments from the local environment and still receive the functions from the remote script?

Comment: (nitpick: the `bash -s` you run there is not a subshell, but a completely independent shell)

Comment: @ilkkachu you are right, subshell is a reserved term for commands enclosed in `(` / `)` which will not influence the parent scope, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the current function arguments are passed to the sourced scripts automatically, so I can just do:

```bash
wexec() {
    url="$1"
    shift
    if command -v "curl" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        \. /dev/stdin <<< "$(curl -s "$url")"
    elif command -v "wget" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        \. /dev/stdin <<< "$(wget -qO- "$url")"
    else
        echo "No curl or wget found." >&2
        return 1
    fi
}
```

This was quite surprising.

I also had to source from `/dev/stdin` to make it work on macOS as well.

Comment: You should always double -quote your variables when you use them. For example `"$url"` instead of `$url`, and `"$@"` instead of `$@`

Comment: @roaima even if I know those arguments will not contain spaces?

Comment: Yes. For example `$@` will not work correctly unless double-quoted, and all unquoted variables are subject to parsing (in your case consider URLs containing `&` or `;`)